# Mac OS X 10.6.6 NetBoot imaged machines running fsck on boot

Tags: mac-osx, startup, fsck, netboot

I have created a NetInstall image of a OS X 10.6.6 machine in our organization for easy deployment of new machines. This has worked out great for us with the exception of the machines running fsck on boot which takes quite some time.

I have just found out that the partition on the NetInstall image does not have Journaling enabled. I assume that the two are related from what I have read on this Apple KB page:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2355

"In an unjournaled file system, drives are in an unknown state after a failure, meaning that there is no record of their activity just prior to the shutdown. Before the server can restart and resume services, it must perform a consistency check that requires going through the entire file system, block by block. This process can take hours on a multi-terabyte volume, resulting in an unacceptable period of server downtime."

Am I correct in assuming so? Will simply enabling Journaling via Disk Utility stop the machine from running fsck on boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with an unjournalled volume, it shouldn't need to run fsck unless the volume wasn't dismounted cleanly last time.  What I'd recommend trying is:

1. Kick all netbooted clients off so you can mess with the image without breaking them.
2. Make a backup copy of the netboot image (just in case).
3. On the server, mount the image (just double-click /Library/NetBoot/NetBootSP0/whatever.nbi/something.dmg).
4. Run Disk Utility, and repair the image volume.
5. Still in Disk Utility, enable journalling on the image volume.
6. Eject the image.

Then netboot a client and see if it's fixed the problem.

Comment: Excuse me let me clarify, the client machines were **net installed** not net booted. Sorry for the confusion on my part. However with that being said enabling Journaling on the net install image and client machines that have already been net installed has fixed the issue. Thank you for your help!